# Why is the error listener is not called for invalid token in my antlr4 grammar?

Tags: c#, antlr4

the start of my top level grammar is:

```
INT2: INT INT;
INT4 :  INT INT INT INT;
DATE: (INT | INT2) SEP (INT | INT2) SEP (INT2 | INT4);
fromdate: DATE;
todate: DATE;
interval: DATES (fromdate DASH todate);

luah: (interval SEMICOLON remainingpart;
```

When I feed it the string:

```
Dates:4/1/2024-4/1/2025 fghyhj
```

it does not generate the error on fghyhj, but token generation stops at a correct place:

```
Token: 'DATES', Text: 'Dates:', Line: '1', Column: '0'
Token: 'DATE', Text: '4/1/2024', Line: '1', Column: '6'
Token: 'DASH', Text: '-', Line: '1', Column: '14'
Token: 'DATE', Text: '4/1/2025', Line: '1', Column: '15'
Token: 'SPACES', Text: ' ', Line: '1', Column: '23'
```

If I feed just an invalid string, like “asdfsdfsedf”, the error handler catches the error:
mismatched input 'asdfsdfsedf' expecting {DATES etc.

I don't understand why fghyhj does not generates the error. Thanks!

Comment: Errors can occur in the lexer and in the parser. Chances are an error _does_ happen but is only printed to your stderr and the parser continues. This is default behavior: possibly recover from invalid input and continue ahead with parsing. This default behavior can be overridden. The information provided in your question is not sufficient to say more. For a better answer, you'd need to edit your question and add a complete, working grammar + driver class.

Comment: Thank you, Bart! You comment forced me to examine the starting grammar where I have "|" parts, but only the first part of the starting rule was used in testing. Removing unused parts make the errors showing correctly. My intentional error "fghyhj" is now correctly recognized as STRING lexer rule and skipped.

Comment: OK, good to hear that.

Comment: Without an EOF in the grammar, the parser simply stops when there is nothing more that it recognizes, regardless of whether there are tokens remaining. Addng an EOF to the end of your `luah` rule would force the parser to deal with the missing SEMI and `fghyhj` text.

Comment: GRosenberg, thank you for the suggestion. Per your advise I added EOF to the grammar. "fghyhj" was still correctly recognized as STRING and skipped, but parser successfully did the entire input and did not stop where this token was not expected. Ideally I want it to stop where unexpected token is found.

Comment: In that case, you want to instead use a [BailErrorStrategy](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BailErrorStrategy.html).